# Update fields with no search query

Tags: java, mongodb

I want to set all my collection documents

> display_contest_finish

field a value, that is set the field with no search query.

```
BasicDBObject newDocument = new BasicDBObject();
    newDocument.append("$set", new BasicDBObject()
    .append("display_contest_finish",value));

    BasicDBObject searchQuery = new BasicDBObject();
    userCollection.update(searchQuery, newDocument);
    return true;
```

Why it don't work? how can I make it work?

I want simple SQL like update query with no where:

> Update table set display_contest_finish = value

Comment: I think you miss `upsert` and `multi` in `update`  try  this
`userCollection.update(searchQuery, newDocument,true,true);`

Comment: @yogesh Why `upsert` ? There is no need to insert missing documents here ?

Answer (score 0):

I am no Java developer so I can not give you the correct syntax. But if I understand your question correctly, you can do something like this in the Mongo shell:

```
db.userCollection.update({}, {$set: {display_contest_finish: "some value"}});
```

The above query will update all you documents with the extra field `display_contest_finish`.